# how is it difference between queryFunction in react-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

hi i'm beginner of react and react-query. 
below code,
it is correctly working!!

```
const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery("comments", () => {
    return fetchComments(post.id);
  });
```

and it is not working.

```
const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery("comments", fetchComments(post.id))
```

What is the difference between these?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In first case, you are giving a function that will call `fetchComments` as a callback function. react-query will take that function and call it, which will call `fetchComments`

in second case, you are immidietaly running fetchComments function and passing returned value as param, and react-query is trying to run whatever `fetchComments` will return, which i assume is Promise and not a function

under some specific circumstances, you can just pass the function refernce without calling it, but you will be unable to pass any props:

```
const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery("comments", fetchAllComments)
```

Your first solution is the correct one.

and suggestion, you can use Arrow function without return, for me its more readable

```
const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery(["comments", post.id], () => fetchComments(post.id));
```

Comment: it is also worth noticing that in the second example, `post.id` should really be part of the queryKey! You'll likely run into problems otherwise